# Python os.listdir encounters invalid argument

Tags: python

I am trying to list all files of a directory. For the folder named "www.cherryhillpolice.com", os.listdir works fine. But for the one named "www.channellogistics.com", it throws an error of invalid argument. I do not see much difference between these two paths. I manually explored the two folders. They do exist.

```
>>> os.listdir( '/media/SAMSUNG/mirror1/www.cherryhillpolice.com' )
['db3c06dd8d6f176d0a988f7caabe511f.html']

>>> os.listdir( '/media/SAMSUNG/mirror1/www.channellogistics.com' )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '/media/SAMSUNG/mirror1/www.channellogistics.com'
```

Comment: What is your expected output for `os.listdir( '/media/SAMSUNG/mirror1/www.channellogistics.com' )`?

Comment: Are you sure you're spelling the second path correctly?  What happens if you do `ls /media/SAMSUNG/mirror1/www.channellogistics.com` in a shell?

Comment: @Elizion I want to list the names of all files in the directory.

Comment: @jwodder "cd /media/SAMSUNG/mirror1/www.channellogistics.com
" works fine. Six files are in the directory.

Comment: Is `www.channellogistics.com` perhaps a symlink to a directory?

Comment: @Munichong What are the names of all the files in the directory?